# MySQL - Exclude conflicting date ranges

Tags: mysql, conflict, date-range

Imagine this list of date ranges

```
> SELECT * FROM range_table;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start      | end        |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-15 | /* -- Not conflicting */
|  2 | 2014-01-15 | 2014-01-16 | /* -- Conflicting     */
|  3 | 2014-01-15 | 2014-01-20 | /* |                  */
|  4 | 2014-01-15 | 2014-01-19 | /* /                  */
|  5 | 2014-01-24 | 2014-01-26 | /* -- Conflicting     */
|  6 | 2014-01-21 | 2014-01-25 | /* /                  */
+----+------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to remove the conflicting ranges and keep only the first occurrence of each conflicting set.

Here is what I should have at the end:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start      | end        |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-15 |
|  2 | 2014-01-15 | 2014-01-16 |
|  5 | 2014-01-24 | 2014-01-26 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f723/1)

Comment: By "first occurrence", you mean the one with the earliest `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my possible solution:

```sql
SELECT `id`, `start`, `end`
FROM (
  SELECT
    r1.id
  , r1.start
  , r1.end
  , COUNT(DISTINCT r2.id) AS "conflicts"
  , MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r2.id ORDER BY r2.id)) AS "group_chksum"
  FROM range_table AS r1
  LEFT JOIN range_table AS r2
    ON (r1.end > r2.start AND r1.start < r2.end)
  GROUP BY r1.id
) AS tmp
GROUP BY group_chksum
;
```

The idea is to group the result by set of ranges and benefit of the tolerance of MySQL to take the first of each.

I'm sure there is simpler

Comment: This is for now the only one actually answering to my question. Yours is smart and I'm sure it'll help other people.

Comment: Hm, I still don't understand the relationship between your data set and your result set. They just don't match up.

Comment: They both contain only 3 fields, `id`, `start`, `end`. Open [the given fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f723/2) and checkout the result

Comment: There is no row with an id of 5 and a date of 2014-01-21

Comment: That's because I forgot to update the whole example when I changed the row order. Updated now

Comment: I've updated my query to suit. Let me know if it's still not right. Getting this one right takes me over the 6k threshold ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM range_table x
  LEFT 
  JOIN range_table y
    ON y.start < x.end 
   AND y.end > x.start 
   AND y.id < x.id
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f723/26

Query amended to suit apparently amended brief

Comment: Do you mean `range_table` instead of `my_table` ? And `y.start >= x.end` instead of `x.start < y.end`. But still, the reader that I am doesn't get the idea.

Comment: Yes... and no... assuming my assumptions are correct. See edit.

Comment: `WHERE y.id IS NULL` can be usefull. Unfortunately (example updated) I don't always have dates ordered.

Comment: In that case I think we can amend as per your suggestion... but note that your amended data set does not correspond with your result set!

Comment: I forgot to update the fiddle link. Now updated. +1 for the idea though